# /api/v1.0/notebooks always returns an empty list

Tags: onenote

When fetching notebooks on my OneDrive account with

```
https://www.onenote.com/api/v1.0/notebooks
```

it always returns an empty list, even though Notebooks exist.

```
{
  "@odata.context": "https://www.onenote.com/api/v1.0/$metadata#notebooks",
  "value":  []
}
```

I can successfully create new notebooks with POST and fetch them by ID so they do exist.

It seems that my account has a default notebook that is corrupt and since there is no way of setting the default notebook I am stuck and have no way of fixing my account. I even have physically deleted all notebooks from OneDrive, then created new ones but to no avail - GET /notebooks always returns an empty list.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Hi Ari, more than likely this is an issue on our side. In the header of the response there should be a key `x-correlationid`. Can you let us know the value of that? It will help us debug further.

Comment: Hi Nick, the correlationid is: `bde3f5c4-125e-404f-b377-40b173de528b`. 
Can you fix this for me?

Comment: Hi Nick,
Have you taken a look at this? You are my only hope to have this fixed . . .  ;)